# Node.js : get content of uploaded file for creating read stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Need your help, I have xhr post request: xhr.send(form.file.files[0]);
I'm trying to upload this file to my server in this way :

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    let pathname = decodeURI(url.parse(req.url).pathname);
    let file = new fs.ReadStream(req);
    let path = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/files' + pathname);

    file.pipe(path);

    file.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        endConnection(res, 500, 'Server Error');
    });

    res.on('close', file.destroy.bind(file));
}
```

The main problem is on line new fs.ReadStream(req); - the argument for ReadStream can contain only string, but req is an object. How can I get uploaded file content from the req?

Comment: This might help: [node js http server request body as stream readable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23573939/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
let writer = fs.createWriteStream(hereFullNameToYourFileOnServer);

request.pipe(writer);
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks, Ilia! :)

Answer (score 2):

Uploaded file are sent as part of a `multipart/form-data` request and one usually use a middleware or other utility to get the file. (A request can also send more than one file).

Check out solutions like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty)